# mvc3 URL routing without action

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, maproute

I have a controller named **article** and my articles in the url take the shape of **{controller}/{action}/{id}/{title}/{mixed}** how can i get that to **{controller}/{id}/{title}/{mixed}**

my route value is

```
routes.MapRoute(
            "articles", 
            "{controller}/{action}/{id}/{stitle}/{mixed}", 
  new { controller = "article",action="detail",mixed= UrlParameter.Optional} // Parameter defaults

        );
```

I have tried this

```
 routes.MapRoute(
            "articles", // Route name
            "{controller}/{id}/{title}/{mixed}",
  new { controller = "article",action="detail",mixed= UrlParameter.Optional}

        );
```

but get a 404 error
as my links are in the form

```
@Html.ActionLink("My article", "detail", "article", new { id = item.ArticleID, title = item.title, mixed = item.mixed })
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
    routes.MapRoute(
        "ArticleWithoutAction",              // Article Without Action name
        "{controller}/{id}/{name}", 
        new { controller = "Article", 
              action     = "detail", 
              id         =  UrlParameter.Optional, 
              title      =  UrlParameter.Optional, 
              mixed      =  UrlParameter.Optional
            } // Parameter defaults
    );

    routes.MapRoute(
        "ArticleWithAction",                  // Article With Action name 
        "{controller}/{action}/{id}/{name}", 
        new { controller = "Article", 
              action     = "detail", 
              id         =  UrlParameter.Optional, 
              title      =  UrlParameter.Optional, 
              mixed      =  UrlParameter.Optional
            } // Parameter defaults
    );

    routes.MapRoute(
        "Default", // Route name
        "{controller}/{action}", 
        new { controller = "Article", 
              action     = "detail" 
            } // Parameter defaults
    );
}
```

Comment: really, no explanation, at all, just a pile of code. #musttryharder